# printing multiple pages in C#

Tags: c#, printing

I would to print 2 pages in my application but when I use this code behind, I'm in a never ending loop.

```
e.HasMorePages = true;

e.Graphics.DrawString("hello", new Font("Verdana", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(10, 10));
e.Graphics.DrawString("page 2", new Font("Verdana", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(10, 2000));
```

If I place `e.HasMorePages = true;` in comment he print only the first page. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @GrantWinney: I think it's e.HasMorePages = true; will make a loop why I don't know. But I'm in a never ending loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.HasMorePages` has no effect in the middle of a print routine. So in your case, create a global variable e.g. `count = 1`, and then:

```
if (count == 1) {
   e.Graphics.DrawString("hello" + count, new Font("Verdana", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(10, 10));
   e.HasMorePages = true;
}
else {
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello Again", New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, 100, 100)
    e.HasMorePages = false;
}

count++;
```

**PS:** I haven't tried this code myself though.